# java.io.StreamCorruptedException: Wrong format: 0x0 with Socket Android app

Tags: android, multithreading, sockets

I make an android client-server app' with a multiclient socket.

The purpose of the application is that I send a class called Communication.

Communication Class I send to clients and they'll return it after treatment, etc... a non-stop communication between Server and Client.

And here's the problem :

> java.io.InvalidClassException: Read null attempting to read class
>   descriptor for an object at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2069)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:929)
>   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2285)
>   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2240)
>   at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(ArrayList.java:662) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521) at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObjectForClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1537)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHierarchy(ObjectInputStream.java:1460)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2139)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:929)
>   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2285)
>   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2240)
>   at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(ArrayList.java:662) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521) at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObjectForClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1537)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHierarchy(ObjectInputStream.java:1460)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2139)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:929)
>   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2285)
>   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2240)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readFieldValues(ObjectInputStream.java:1305)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:530)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObjectForClass(ObjectInputStream.java:1552)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readHierarchy(ObjectInputStream.java:1460)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2139)
>   at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:929)
>   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2285)
>   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2240)
>   at com.drawid.communication.Client$SocketClient.run(Client.java:153)

This message refers to the line

```
donnees = (Communication) in.readObject();
```

of the client.

Sometimes, I get this message :

> java.io.StreamCorruptedException: Wrong format: 0x0

And I have no idea... Can anyone help me please ? I searched for a long time but I found nothing.

Please somebody can tell me whats wrong with my code ?

Ah yes! I want to say that communication works fine for a while, and then comes the error, thats why I didnt understand this problem ! Thats works a while and... no more...

Thanks very much and I sorry for my english !